# UITapGestureRecognizer on a UIButton

Tags: iphone, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a UIButton which has an IBAction as well as a UITapGestureRecognizer to detect double taps.

At the moment it looks like the IBAction is blocking the recognizer. Is there a way to stop this or do  UITapGestureRecognizer even work on buttons? If so wouldn't it be better to just add the recognizers and remove the IBActions?

EDIT

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget : self action : @selector (handleDoubleTap:)];
[doubleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
[A1 addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
[A2 addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
[B1 addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
```

Comment: Gesture recognizer will work on a button but are you doing different things depending on single or double tap?  Button seems a little non-intuitive for this.  Blocking should actually be happening the other way around. Some code might help.

Comment: I have a doubleTap on the Gesture recognizer and the obvious 1 tap triggers the IBAction.

Comment: Show the code that adds the recognizer to the button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to attach one gesture recognizer to multiple buttons.  A gesture recognizer can only be attached to one view at a time.  So in your case, the last button you are attaching the recognizer to (button B1) probably responds to the double tap but A1 and A2 don't.

Create a separate recognizer for each button.
But all three recognizers can call the same action method (`handleDoubleTap:`).

However, when you try to do a single tap on a button, there will be a slight delay as it waits to see if it's the beginning of a double tap.  There are ways to reduce the delay but may not be worth it if you can live with the delay and the workarounds bring up other issues.

**Edit:**
In your comment, you say you "want to detect if they are pressed at the same time".  To do this, you don't need gesture recognizers.  You can just use the standard control events provided.

Next, in IB, for ***each*** button, hook up the "Touch Down" event with `buttonPressed:`.  Or, to do it programmatically:

```
[button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button3 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

Next, in IB, for ***each*** button, hook up the "Touch Up Inside" ***and*** "Touch Up Outside" events with `buttonReleased:`.  Or, to do it programmatically:

```
[button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonReleased:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside|UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
[button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonReleased:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside|UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
[button3 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonReleased:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside|UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
```

Next, add ivars to keep track of how many or which buttons are pressed:

```
@property (nonatomic) int numberOfButtonsBeingTouched;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableSet *buttonsBeingTouched; //alloc + init in viewDidLoad or similar
```

If you just care how many buttons are pressed, you don't need the `NSMutableSet`.

Finally, add the buttonPressed and buttonReleased methods:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)button {
    self.numberOfButtonsBeingTouched++;
    [self.buttonsBeingTouched addObject:button];
    //your logic here (if (self.numberOfButtonsBeingTouched == 3) ...)
}

- (IBAction)buttonReleased:(UIButton *)button {
    self.numberOfButtonsBeingTouched--;
    [self.buttonsBeingTouched removeObject:button];
    //your logic (if any needed) here
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks. Is there a way to detect multiple taps, like 2 or 3 simultaneous taps, each on a single button ? but I want to detect this via another way other than checking each button and somehow linking that they are being touched at the same time. Thanks

Comment: To detect multiple fingers simultaneously, you use the UITapGestureRecognizer and set numberOfTapsRequired to 1 and numberOfTouchesRequired to 2 (or 3 or whatever).  I don't understand the second part of your comment.  You might want to update your question with an explanation of what functionality you are trying to get.  Maybe using buttons and gesture recognizers is not right for this case.

Comment: I have multiple buttons and want to detect if they are pressed at the same time.

Comment: Thanks. What is the touch up outside for?

Comment: The user could touch down on the button then move their finger off the button and then lift it up.  If you don't include Touch Up Outside, the button they originally touched will still be considered "touched".

Comment: What I meant by detecting multiple buttons touched at the same time, was using more than one finger. Maybe I misunderstood the above comment, but I dont want them to be able to touch a button and lift up outside.

Comment: Here's an example: Finger A touches down on button1 (buttonsTouched now equals 1).  Finger B touches down on button2 (buttonsTouched now equals 2).  Finger A (without lifting) slides outside of button1 and THEN lifts (buttonsTouched now equals 1).  If TouchUpOutside is not included, then in this example, buttonsTouched would still be 2 even though only one finger (Finger B) is touching a button.  Try playing with the sample code in the answer.  Put NSLogs in the buttonPressed and buttonReleased methods to see the results and you're welcome to modify as needed for your requirements.

Comment: Cool. I want it to still add to buttonsTouched even if the finger is lifted outside. As long as the initial touch is on the button its fine. Thanks. ;)