# is Gesture Recognization working on buttons or not?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, gesture-recognition

In my app, I wrote these lines of code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapper = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)];

[mybutton1 addGestureRecognizer:tapper];
[mybutton2 addGestureRecognizer:tapper];
[mybutton3 addGestureRecognizer:tapper];

    [tapper release];
}

-(void)tapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender{
NSLog(@"I'am in tapped");


}
```

but nothing happened. why ? and if I need to get the button's currentTitle inside tapped, can I ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the recognizer delegate. Implement that. You should also add the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` protocol to your header file and make `recognizer.delegate = self`.

re: getting the title - you can get the title. in your tap event handler you can extract that information from the sender object. i'll post some code later...

Comment: ok Im wanting u remember that i have 8 buttons and every button play a sound (Drag are very important)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a gesture recogniser just to detect when a button is pressed. A button knows when it's being pressed!

Try:

```
{
  // Blah...
  [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

  // Other stuff
}

-(void)tapped:(id)sender {
  NSLog (@"I'm in tapped!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A gesture recognizer can only be attached to one view at a time. Handling single taps on buttons can just as easily be done using IBAction. You can create one IBAction and connect all three buttons to it.

```
- (IBAction)tapped:(id)sender {
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
NSLog(@"%@", button.titleLabel.text);
}
```

A similar question: [UITapGestureRecognizer on a UIButton](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4105293/143)