# Double tap on a button

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, action

How can I add an action for a double tap on my button?

Answer (score 11):

```
- (void) buttonTouchDownRepeat:(id)sender event:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    if(touch.tapCount == 2) {
        NSLog(@"Twice");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"otherwise");
    }
}
```

Comment: To register this event call `[control addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTouchDownRepeat:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat];`

Comment: can we get single tap from this function?

Comment: @souvickcse : `if(touch.tapCount == 1)`

Comment: no for touch_down_repeat its not possible to get touch.tapcount==1, have to use touch_down

Answer (score 5):

In IB or code, connect an action to the button's `UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat` event. The action method should have a signature like this:

```
- (void) buttonTouchDownRepeat:(id)sender event:(UIEvent *)event
```

In the method's implementation, you can access a `UITouch` instance with `[[event allTouches] anyObject]` and then check the touch's `tapCount` value.

Comment: I'm very noobie, explain better ?

Answer (score 1):

Of course, if you want to be super StackOverFlow cool programming wiz? Then use [UITapGestureRecognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105293/uitapgesturerecognizer-on-a-uibutton)...

Granted it's only available for recent iOS, don't try it on 3.0;)