# Double tap on a UIButton

Tags: iphone, uibutton

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Double tap on a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608006/double-tap-on-a-button)

Hi, I find on foruns that to me detect 2 taps I use this code:

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *) touches withEvent:(UIEvent *) event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if (touch.tapCount == 2)
    {
        nosi=nosi-1;
        if (nosi<10) {
            nos.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%i", nosi];
        } else {
            nos.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", nosi];
        }
    }
}
```

But, how I detect 2 taps in a button ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

subclass UIButton and put that code in ;)

but I think that's kind of a strange UI experience, double tapping a button.

Answer (score 0):

I answered this question already once today...

Use [UITapGestureRecognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105293/uitapgesturerecognizer-on-a-uibutton)...

Granted it's only available for recent iOS, don't try it on 3.0;)